# ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, gcc

El error que me salta es este:

> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Mi código fuente es éste, **calculadora.cpp:**

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int n1=0,n2=0;
    char opcion;
    // acentos: std::cout<<"\240\202\241\242\243";
    system("cls");
    std::cout<<"Bienvenido a la aplicaci\242n de operadores l\242gicos.";std::cout<<std::endl;std::cout<<"Indique qu\202 opci\242n quiere realizar:";std::cout<<std::endl;std::cout<<"1. Suma.\n2. Resta.\n3. Multiplicaci\242n.\n4. Divisi\242n.\n0. Salir.\n\nOpci\242n: ";std::cin>>opcion;
    system("pause");
    switch (opcion){
        case '0':{return 0;break;}
        case '1':{system("cls");std::cout<<"Suma\n\n1er n\243mero: ";std::cin>>n1;std::cout<<"2do n\243mero: ";std::cin>>n2;std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la suma es: ";int n3=n1+n2;std::cout<<n3;std::cout<<"\n";system("pause");main();}break;
        case '2':{system("cls");std::cout<<"Resta\n\n1er n\243mero: ";std::cin>>n1;std::cout<<"2do n\243mero: ";std::cin>>n2;std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la resta es: "; int n3=n1-n2;std::cout<<n3;std::cout<<"\n";system("pause");main();}break;
        case '3':{system("cls");std::cout<<"Multiplicaci\242n\n\n1er n\243mero: ";std::cin>>n1;std::cout<<"2do n\243mero: ";std::cin>>n2;std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la multiplicaci\242 es: "; int n3=n1*n2;std::cout<<n3;std::cout<<"\n";system("pause");main();}break;
        case '4':{system("cls");std::cout<<"Divisi\242n\n\n1er n\243mero: ";std::cin>>n1;std::cout<<"2do n\243mero: ";std::cin>>n2;std::cout<<"\nEl resultado de la divisi\242n es: "; int n3=n1/n2;std::cout<<n3;std::cout<<"\n";system("pause");main();}break;
        default:std::cout<<"Introduzca una opci\242n correcta.";system("pause");main();break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son tus datos de entrada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por favor, deja respirar a tu código. Poner decenas de instrucciones de código en una línea no hará que sea mejor, más bien lo contrario.

---

En los 90 teníamos pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto, entonces era necesario apelotonar el código para que cupiera cuanto más código en pantalla mejor. Por suerte esa época quedó atrás y ahora podemos ver mucho más código en pantalla sin grandes dificultades, por lo tanto, separa las líneas y el contenido; de esta manera tu código será mucho más fácil de entender y depurar.

Si te tomas la molestia de separar el código de manera más legible, verás que tienes mucha información redundante, todas las opciones de tu `switch` siguen esta estructura:

```
case '1': {
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Suma\n\n1er n\243mero: ";
    std::cin >> n1;
    std::cout << "2do n\243mero: ";
    std::cin >> n2;
    std::cout << "\nEl resultado de la suma es: ";
    int n3 = n1 + n2;
    std::cout << n3;
    std::cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    main();
} break;
```

Borrar pantalla, mostrar texto, pedir datos, operar y re-llamar `main`. Según [el estándar de C++](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/) está explícitamente prohibido llamar `main`:

> #### 6.6.1 La función `main`

3. La función `main` no debe ser usada en el programa.

Al saltarte la prohibición impuesta por el estándar, tu programa puede comportarse de manera errática e impredecible, por ejemplo: mostrando un error.

Si lo que quieres es que el programa se repita en un ciclo, usa un bucle:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
    char opcion = 0;

    std::cout << "Bienvenido a la aplicaci\242n de operadores l\242gicos.\n"
                "Indique qu\202 opci\242n quiere realizar:\n"
                 "1. Suma.\n2. Resta.\n3. Multiplicaci\242n.\n4. Divisi\242n.\n0. Salir.\n\nOpci\242n: ";
    std::cin >> opcion;

    while (opcion != 0) {
        std::cout << "Primer numero";
        std::cin >> n1;
        std::cout << "Segundo numero: ";
        std::cin >> n2;

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "El resultado de la suma es: " << n1 + n2;
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "El resultado de la resta es: " << n1 - n2;
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "El resultado de la multiplicacion es: " << n1 * n2;
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "El resultado de la division es: " << n1 / n2;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Opcion incorrecta";
                break;
        }

        std::cout << "Bienvenido a la aplicaci\242n de operadores l\242gicos.\n"
                    "Indique qu\202 opci\242n quiere realizar:\n"
                     "1. Suma.\n2. Resta.\n3. Multiplicaci\242n.\n4. Divisi\242n.\n0. Salir.\n\nOpci\242n: ";
        std::cin >> opcion;
    }

    return 0;
}
```